# In ReactJS todo app I am trying to set input field text state into another state which is array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing simple todo app. I have 1 input box and Add button. On typing into input box and clicking Add button the text is displayed in a list below. I am using below constructor:

```
    class Entry extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super()
            this.state = {
                st_search_field: '',
                st_lists: [
                    { 
                      list_id: new Date(`enter code here`), 
                      list_name: ''
                    }
                ]
            }
         }
```

Now I create `list_handler = () => { ...... }` function to set search_field text into list_name value. I use list_handler method during onClick for Add button.  I have started by using`const join = Object.assign({}, this.state)` in list_handler function and tried using `this.setState({st_lists.list_name: this.state.st_searh_field})` but`st_lists.list_name` is marked in red in VS editor. Tried `this.state.st_lists.map(li => {})` above setState method but even that gives error.

Comment: In `this.setState({st_lists.list_name: this.state.st_searh_field})` `st_lists.list_name` is not a valid key name javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can't set state on one of states sub objects do it like this:

```
  const st_lists = this.state.st_lists;
  st_lists.list_name = this.state.st_search_field;
  this.setState({st_lists});
```

Comment: Hi Geoman, if I can add little bit. '''const st_lists = this.state.st_lists;''' might mutate state directly. So, I went with '''const st_lists = Object.assign([], this.state.st_lists) or const st_lists = [...this.state.st_lists]'''. Rest is same i guess.

Answer (score 0):

`st_lists.list_name` is not a key, you need to add merge the object

```
this.setState({
    st_lists: [
        {
            ...this.state.st_lists,
            list_name: this.state.st_searh_field,
        },
    ]
})
```

Comment: Tried this way and it was ale to set state on clicking Add button. Though I would like to re-confirm upon re-working on the functionality once again. Thanks Ewe.

Comment: No problem, take care!